# Database Design: Many ugly columns, or separated into rows

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database and I've hit a spot where I'm not sure which is the preferable design, so I decided to get some input here.

The problem is that I have several repeating pieces of data for columns, along the lines of

page1:

```
aName, aSize, aColor
bName, bSize, bColor
cName, cSize, cColor
```

page2:

```
aName, aSize, aColor
bName, bSize, bColor
cName, cSize, cColor
```

etc.

So I could have a design like this:

```
[pageId] [aName] [aSize] [aColor] [bName] [bSize] [bColor] etc.
```

Or split it into rows

```
[pageId] [letter] [name] [size] [color]
```

The former is better for performance, while the latter appears more clean.  Is there a better way to approach the problems than these two options?  I'm working with PHP and MySQL, but I'm interested in any solutions regardless of platform.

Comment: "appears more clean"?  You should probably read up on Normalization and revise your question.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I'm aware of normalization.  I'm not having an issue here duplicating data (sorry if I wasn't clear).  There are a fixed number of sections (a, b, c, etc.) on every page with the same type of data (name, size, color), but could all be stored without redundancy in one row.  In multiple rows, the rows could be identified by the section and access the individual properties directly without having to prefix the column name repeatedly.  That is what I meant by "more clean".

Comment: Repeating data is a First Normal Form violation. Please update your question to indicate that you **know** what First Normal Form means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use option 2 as you are likely to end up with cleaner code because you can now iterate over the letter.

Maybe that's not useful in the production site, but might come in handy in scripts or the admin site.

Also the performance should not be too bad, as the roundtrip to the server will outweigh fetch 3 smaller rows.

Answer (score 3):

## Normalize

If you have a, b, and c sections today, you may have d and e sections tomorrow. Or the c section may go away.